# Cannot get OTP when use Sms Retriever

Tags: android, sms, one-time-password

I'm trying to use Google's SMS Retriever API for Automatic SMS Verification. I have followed the directions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) but my app is not receiving any SMS messages. I've tried many ways but it's still not working and I really don't understand why.

Here is what I've done. First I create class `MySMSBroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MySMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public OTPReceiveListener otpReceiveListener;
    public void initOtpReceiveListener(OTPReceiveListener otpReceiveListener) {
        this.otpReceiveListener = otpReceiveListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

            switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // Get SMS message contents
                    String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                    otpReceiveListener.onOTPReceived(message);
                    break;
                case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                    otpReceiveListener.onOTPTimeOut();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OTPReceiveListener {

        void onOTPReceived(String otp);
        void onOTPTimeOut();
    }

}
```

For class `OTPActivity`, I remove unrelated code:

```
public class OTPActivity extends BaseActivity implements IDelegateResponse<OTPResponse>, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, MySMSBroadcastReceiver.OTPReceiveListener {

    @BindView(R.id.edtSmsOtp)
    EditText edtSmsOtp;

    private final String TAG = "OTPActivity";
    private MySMSBroadcastReceiver mySMSBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    public int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.activity_otp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setUpOTPSms();
    }

    private void setUpOTPSms() {
        AppSignatureHelper appSignatureHelper = new AppSignatureHelper(OTPActivity.this);
        Utils.showLog(TAG, "getAppSignatures:" + appSignatureHelper.getAppSignatures());

        mySMSBroadcastReceiver = new MySMSBroadcastReceiver();
        mySMSBroadcastReceiver.initOtpReceiveListener(this);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.setPriority(2147483647);
        registerReceiver(mySMSBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        startSMSListener();
   }

    private void startSMSListener() {
        SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(OTPActivity.this);
        Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
            //Toast.makeText(OTPActivity.this, "SMS Retriever starts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Utils.showLog(TAG, "SMS Retriever starts");
        });
        task.addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(OTPActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOTPReceived(String otp) {
        if (mySMSBroadcastReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mySMSBroadcastReceiver);
        }

        Utils.showLog("OTP Received", "OTP: " + otp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOTPTimeOut() {
        Utils.showLog("OTP Received", "onOTPTimeOut");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mySMSBroadcastReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mySMSBroadcastReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get the sms permission ?

Comment: What kind of permission, i just add **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />**

Comment: try this 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

Comment: It's not true, i think, because Google's SMS Retriever API don't need permission

Comment: yes you are right man, the problem is something else

Comment: yeppp, thank for your help

Comment: Did you find a solution ? i'm having same problem, but if i keep breakpoints inside my reciever and send message to myself from same phone it works, but if i run the app and send sms from other numbers it wont work.

Comment: not yet :)). please try some solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add any *Permission in Manifest* for **OPT** to work. 
Follow the given code (is in Kotlin, easy to implement and it's working).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val smsBroadcastReceiver by lazy { SMSBroadcastReceiver() }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this)
    val retriever = client.startSmsRetriever()
    retriever.addOnSuccessListener {

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Listener started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val otpListener = object : SMSBroadcastReceiver.OTPListener {
            override fun onOTPReceived(otp: String) {
                customCodeInput.setText(otp)
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, otp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onOTPTimeOut() {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"TimeOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        smsBroadcastReceiver.injectOTPListener(otpListener)
        registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION))
    }
    retriever.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Problem to start listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    unregisterReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver)
}}
```

**SMSBroadcastReceiver** is as follows :

```
class SMSBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

private var otpReceiver: OTPListener? = null

fun injectOTPListener(receiver: OTPListener?) {
    this.otpReceiver = receiver
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
        val extras = intent.extras
        val status = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

        when (status.statusCode) {

            CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {

                val message = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE) as String

                val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}")
                val matcher = pattern.matcher(message)

                if (matcher.find()) {
                    otpReceiver?.onOTPReceived(matcher.group(0))
                    return
                }
            }
            CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                otpReceiver?.onOTPTimeOut()
            }
        }
    }
}

interface OTPListener {


    fun onOTPReceived(otp: String)

    fun onOTPTimeOut()
}}
```

PS : If you still face difficulties let me know.

Comment: I test and it't work perfect but in my project with Java Code, it's still not work.

Answer (score 1):

Google recently has changed sms strategy. Now you have to send sms , the OTP this way:

1. The message (otp) should start with the prefix <#>
2. The message (otp) must be no longer than 140 bytes
3. The message (otp) should end with the 11-character
   hash string that identifies your app.

This post will be [helpfully](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827)

Comment: I do as the same, that is my message *<#> SampleApp: Your verification code is 143567 32urg60XXXX* but it's not work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the play services version on your emulator/device is > 10.2.0

Comment: Thank for answer but google play services is 15.0.90 in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check your menifest as well

1.have you added following code in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MySMSBroadcastReceiver" 
          android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2. add dependancy

   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to retrieve OTP only for android I would recommend you this [package SMS](https://pub.dev/packages/sms) this works pretty well on android and its just 2 lines of code
to get fetch the incoming sms;

Create an instance of receiver

```
SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
```

in your initstate listen for the incoming sms as

```
receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => print(msg.body));
```

This works really well but unfortunately this package doesnt support ios